# binary tree building recursively

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, nlp, binary-tree

i have a basic text

```
text = "The user's Average Revenue Per User (ARPU) has experienced a significant decrease due to high decrement and they have been inactive in terms of outgoing voice calls, data usage, and SMS for a consecutive period of 5 days. or they are having handset"
```

there are conjunctions present in the text they are

```
conjunctions  = [and , and , or ]
```

what i am trying to do is to build a tree like this
[image]
the code which i wrote

```
import spacy


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, text=None):
        self.text = text
        pass

    def parse_left(self, conj_list, text):
        conj_index = cont_index_list[0][0]
        conj = str(conj_list[0][1])
        left = text.split(conj)[0]
        self.text = f"{conj}".join(self.text.split(conj)[1:])
        return left

    def parse_right(self, text, conj_list):
        # conj_index = cont_index_list[0][0]
        conj = str(conj_list[0][1])
        conj_next = None
        try:
            conj_next = str(conj_list[1][1])
        except:
            print("last conj")

        right = text.split(f" {conj} ")[0]
        self.text = f"{conj}".join(self.text.split(conj)[1:])
        # right = right.split(conj_next)
        return right

    def recursion_tree(self, node, text, conj_list):

        # code for if the text len is empty then return the tree

        # if ndoe is none create a leaf node
        if node is None:
            n1 = Node(conj_list[0][1])
            left = self.parse_left(conj_list, self.text)
            conj_list.pop(0)
            right = self.parse_right(self.text, conj_list)
            conj_list.pop(0)
            n1.left = left
            n1.right = right
            self.recursion_tree(n1, self.text, conj_list)
        else:
            n1 = Node(conj_list[0][1])
            n1.left = node
            right = self.parse_right(self.text, conj_list)
            n1.right = right
            self.recursion_tree(n1, self.text, conj_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Load the spaCy model
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    node = None
    text = "The user's Average Revenue Per User (ARPU) has experienced a significant decrease due to high decrement and they have been inactive in terms of outgoing voice calls, data usage, and SMS for a consecutive period of 5 days. or they are having handset"
    doc = nlp(text)
    # Extract conjunctions
    conjunctions = [token for token in doc if token.dep_ in {'cc', 'mark'} or token.pos_ == "CONJ"]
    conj_list = []
    cont_index_list = []

    for i in range(len(conjunctions)):
        print(i)
        conj_list.append((i, conjunctions[i]))
        cont_index_list.append((i, text.index(conjunctions[i].text)))
    p = Parser(text=text)
    p.recursion_tree(node, text, conj_list)
```

the logic which i am doing is wrong
should i take the middle conjunction and start building the tree from there recursively ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your expected vs actual outputs are; when I run your code it enters an infinite loop. It's not clear to me that you'll be able to extract a tree with nothing more than a linear list of conjunctions, but I'm going to assume you have your reasons.

Some things that may help you:

- Fix your infinite loop at line 56; you're not properly handling the edge case.
- Print out the final tree, so you can see what you've built.
- Or, step through in a debugger. Here's what I see when I run your code:

[image]

You've created a tree structure, and the lower left node looks the way I think you want it to. But you can see that the parent of that node (`<__main__.Node object at 0x7fbe03dbb550>`) thinks that its conjunction value is `or`, when in your diagram you're expecting the `and`.

My first guess is that this simply because your leaf processing code pops 2 conjunctions, so you immediately swallowed your second `and`.

To summarize:

- assuming your premise of parsing a tree from a linear list of conjunctions for your use case is sound, your algorithm is probably ok.
- but your code isn't. At the very least it loops infinitely, but even that aside it's not building your tree the way you want it constructed.